# iOS 5 Black screen after segue

Tags: objective-c, ios5, ios-simulator

I have an iOS 5 application with a storyboard and two scenes. Scene 1 is a selection list while Scene 2 shows details for each selection

In Scene 1 I need to pass a variable and I do that with:

```
//Handles the selection 
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Guests *myGuests =[guestList objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

    selectedGuest = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have selected %@", myGuests.guestID];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"TGG" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"TGG"]){
        GuestDetailsViewController *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
        [vc setGuestSelected:selectedGuest];
    }
}
```

In Scene 2 (details) I use this to verify that the right variable was received like this

```
// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSString *msg = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"You have selected %@", guestSelected];
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selection" message:msg delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];          

     nameCell.textLabel.text= msg;

    [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

All of this works fine and the alert box shows the right variable and there is a transition to the new scene. HOWEVER, the alert box displays a total of 5 times over & over and, once completed, the whole window is black. Nothing from my scene (Scene 2) is displayed at that point. So I know I have the right segue, it transitions as desired, I just can't see anything on my screen.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

i ran into a situation very similar. i had unintentionally un-commented the method:

```
-(void)loadView
```

i **believe** this method overrides the IB interface and created it from this code instead. check to make sure it is either removed or commented out IMHO.

Comment: You have GOT to be kidding me. This was the right answer. Man, I hate how the small things just come up and bite you! Thanks for the help.

Comment: That is just... bad.  I am learning ios and this was KILLING me. I was about ready to delete the project and start again.  Thanks a bunch.

Comment: This worked for one of my scenes but not for the other one. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: BTW this is what fixed the second one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20502769/1533054