# Can I not 'pushModalViewController'?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I have a UIViewController class and a second which I want to push modally preferably. However I can't seem to call `[self pushModalViewController:...]`, how come?

What requirements do I need to meet to be able to do so?

I am doing this and getting a black view pushed:

```
vc = [[ViewController alloc] init];
    [vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
    [self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

I have made my view controller in my storyboard and given it a custom class. I am trying to present this view modally via this class as seen in my code.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Do you mean presentModalViewController:animated:?

Comment: Doh! Your right Emilio, thanks for correcting me there. Although I am only seeing a black view when using this.

Comment: for the black screen, try this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945292/ios-5-black-screen-after-segue/8945392#8945392

Comment: Didn't work uncommenting the `loadView` method. I have made my view controller in my storyboard and given it a custom class. I am trying to present this view modally via this class as seen in my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'push' and 'modal' don't belong together in the same thought. You can:

- present a modal view controller, preferably using `-presentViewController:animated:completion:`, which is the modern replacement for `-presentModalViewController:animated:`
- push a view controller onto the navigation stack, assuming that you're using a UINavigationController. To do that from a view controller, use:

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:foo animated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You're actually looking for [self presentModalViewController:myViewController.view animated:YES]

Answer (score 0):

How are you initing this viewcontroller. From the posted code, I assume it is being initialized to a blank view.
Maybe you can init it from a nibname or something?

```
vc = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NibName" bundle:nil];
[vc setModalTransitionStyle:UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

Also another thing to note, if this is a custom class and no nib file, is there any code in initWithCoder? How does the viewDidLoad looks like?

Comment: No nib file as it was made in a storyboard. No initWithCoder method in custom class. viewDidLoad just has [super viewDidLoad] in. Any more ideas?

Comment: I just tried after having removed the link to the custom class in my storyboard and it now works. So what requirements are there in the custom class to make sure the view controller loads correctly?