# Perform Segue after login check

Tags: iphone, xcode4, ios5, storyboard, segue

I'm somewhat new to iphone development.. so please bear with me!

I have a login screen that connects to my REST API I developed. It sends json requests back and forth. Basically when you click LOGIN, it checks whether the username/password was valid (obviously).

Here's the basic logic of what I have:

```
- (IBAction)sendLoginJson:(id)sender {

   // send JSON request to server.. etc

   NSURLConnection *myConnection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
   [myConnection start]; 
}
```

Then goes to

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading
   // this is where I get the response from the server
```

How do I switch to, say, "DashboardViewController" after I make sure the login was verified correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can manually perform segues.
When you create a segue in the storyboard, instead of Ctrl+Dragging from a button to a View Controller, drag from the View Controller to another View Controller.
Give the segue a name, then in your code you call [self performseguewithidentifier@"seguename"]

Comment: Darren, thanks for that. It worked like a charm. However, for some reason when it switches to the Dashboard Segue, it goes black. Any ideas?

Comment: Does the Dashboard have a view?

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945292/ios-5-black-screen-after-segue

Comment: Thank you Darren! All I had to do was comment out the viewLoad()