# Simple segue scenario not working

Tags: storyboard

Here is a simple scenario I created.

1. Created a new single view project with story board.
2. Added a new view controller to the storyboard from object library. At this point there are two view controllers on the storyboard. One, original one, which has actual class/interface attached to it. Second doesn't. I added a button on first view
   controller and second view controller.
3. I created a segue from first VC to second VC using Modal.
4. Attached an on click function to the first view controller button. It has perfromsegue call.

5 Ran the app, clicking the button on first VC works well, I see second view controller with button. Great

1. Now I create another view controller file and attached it to the second view controller in the storyboard. Also ctrl-dragged the button in the .h file.
2. Now I ran the application. When I click on the button the first view controller, I SEE BLANK SCREEN ???

What am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing the -(void)loadView method as suggested here:

[iOS 5 Black screen after segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945292/ios-5-black-screen-after-segue)