# ios 6 prepareForSegue leads to a black screen

Tags: ios6, storyboard, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I'm having troubles using the storyboard.

I properly connected a button (inside a custom `uiviewcell`) to a scene (`ProfileVC`) through push segue (whose identifier is `pic2profile`).
Besides in the table view controller (`HomeVC`) that manages the cells I implemented the method `prepareForSegue`:

```
- (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"pic2profile"]){
        ProfileVC *profile = (ProfileVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        NSLog(@"%@", [segue identifier]);
        Tweet *tweet = [tweets objectAtIndex:0];
        profile.user = tweet.user;  
    }
}
```

As explained in the documentation, once called `segue.destinationViewController` at the end of `prepareForSegue` should be displayed the view controller at the end of the segue (`ProfileVC` in this case).
What happen is that I get (no errors!) a black screen and the method `viewDidLoad` in `ProfileVC` is not called though the object "profile" is not null.

Inside the storyboard the ProfileVC scene is linked to its view controller (ProfileVC) and is also set up a Storyboard ID.

I already tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945292/ios-5-black-screen-after-segue) but it didn't work.

Comment: Is your current view controller managed by a navigation controller?  (Try logging `self.navigationController` in `prepareForSegue:` to be sure.)

Comment: Yes it is. HomeVC in the storyboard is embedded in a navigation controller. Indeed when I tap the button connected to ProfileVC I get a black screen with a navigation bar on top (I can go back to HomeVC).

Comment: What do you mean the scene is "linked" with the viewController?

Answer (score 0):

Are you performing a segue to a view controller using the code you have, but have a navigation controller in between? If so you have to use a different way, specifying the navigation controller in between.

If you don't need the navigation controller you can delete it and connect the cell to the view controller and keep the code you have. Otherwise you have to change it.