# Black screen on segue. Never seen this before

Tags: ios

I'm putting together a demo in Xcode 5.0.2 for iOS7 and have wired up some scenes and have some buttons, some view controller classes and some segues. Nothing out of the ordinary. What I've never seen before is that intermittently - on some builds - when performing a segue, the next view controller is all black after the push. But not all the time. Sometimes it works in the simulator, sometimes it works on the device.

I've never seen this before in 3 years of programming for iOS.

Looking around StackExchange, I see answers that don't explain why it's happening in my case. I don't have a (void)loadView method in either of my classes and this wouldn't explain why it's intermittent.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour before?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT 01**: turning off AutoLayout appears to fix this but opens up other problems.  I still have no idea why this is happening.

**EDIT 02**: multiple view outlets issue, not AutoLayout related.

Comment: Without code it's going to be really hard for us to figure out...

Comment: The first segue is sent from a button as a result of an action.  There is no code being called.

Comment: Well, there's something that causes this. I guess start stripping code from your view controller (especially in the lifecycle methods) until it doesn't happen anymore. As far as I know, this is not a known bug or anything.

Comment: The first segue is sent from a button as a result of an action.  There is no code being called.  An action to do a modal push to a navigation controller is attached to a button.  When the VC that is attached to the nav controller appears, I have a UIViewController with tableView protocols.  In it are viewdidLoad and ViewWillAppear methods that are called.  There is no loadView method.  InitWithNibName is present but is not called.  Again, this is intermittent happening on some builds, but not on others.  Does this help?

Comment: It's weird that it only happens occasionally. I'm guessing that every time you get a black screen, initWithNibName is not called? Or is it never called? Maybe post the code for `viewDidLoad` and `viewWillAppear:`?

Comment: FYI, it's an AutoLayout issue.  Disabling AutoLayout solves the problem.

Comment: maybe you should post the code to github, so everyone could try to reproduce it?

Answer (score 3):

OK.  Here's what happened.  I'm on a slow Mac with 4 GB of RAM.  What caused the error was two view outlets on the tableView.  One to the parent view and one to the tableView itself.  The reason this happened was that the Mac is slow when dragging out lines to wire up the storyboards and I didn't see if one of the attempts to wire up the view outlet hit the tableView and connected, so I did it again.  It actually did wire up the view outlet, but to the parent view.  This resulted in two view outlets for the tableView.  What is odd is that intermittently, one was chosen over the other.  It wasn't deterministic.  Thinking about this, this information may be stored in an internal dictionary which is inherently unordered.

So, when I duplicated that scene, I now had two scenes with the same multiple view connection issue.  If it didn't happen on one, it might happen on the other.

Damn confusing but solved.

Thanks for the input.  It's greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had the exact same problem on two of my scenes, this fixed one of them. The other one was fixed because of this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8945392/1533054

Answer (score 2):

A new twist in iOS8: pertaining to blank screens.

I know this post was about iOS7, but :
In 8, the storyboard is one to fit all, and changing the sizing parameters will also cause missing buttons, pics, and whatever else doesn't fit as well.

Paul

Comment: Yeah, autolayout and size classes were the bane of my existence this morning.  Sweet mother of suck, these are horrible.